# Socket.io socket listener not updating in nextjs api

Tags: node.js, websocket, next.js, socket.io

I have a Next.js project that has the simplest Socket.IO implementation set up. Below is the code.

```js
//  pages/index.tsx

let socket: Socket;
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function socketInit() {
      //start server
      await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/socket");

      // connects to the socket
      socket = io();
      socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("hello");
      });
    }

    socketInit();
  }, []);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        socket.emit("test");
      }}
    >
      hello
    </button>
  );
};
```

```js
//  pages/api/socket.ts

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: Res
) {
  if (res.socket.server.io) { res.end(); return; }

  const io = new IOServer(res.socket.server);
  res.socket.server.io = io;
  io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('test', () => {
      console.log("1");  //Changing it to "2" doesn't do anything until dev is restarted.
    });
  });

  res.end();
}
```

For some reason, the `listener` in the server would not update from hot reload. Restarting the dev is the only way. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 issues here:

1. The response object that you instantiate the `IOServer` on is not recreated after a HMR, it is still referring to the callback function that prints `1`, which is hanging around in memory somewhere.
2. To fix this, you need to actively call the handler method, unsubscribe the old callback function and resubscribe the new (replaced) callback function. Just interacting with through the socket is not enough. Unfortunately, all tutorials I have seen call the handler `socket`, which is misleading. It should be called `setup-socket-handler` instead. What it does is retrieve the actual server from the response object of this handler and register a `IOSocket` server with the underlying server, which will then register a new handler/endpoint `/socket.io` that will be used for the communication between client and server.

Here is what I came up with. This should not be used as is in production (make sure the replacement happens only once in production, as it did in the original):

```js
const SocketHandler = (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponseWithSocket
): void => {
  if (res.socket.server.io != null) {
    logger.info("Socket is already running");
    res.socket.server.io.removeAllListeners("connection");
    res.socket.server.io.on("connection", onConnection);
  } else {
    logger.info("Socket is initializing");
    const io = new Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents>(
      res.socket.server
    );
    io.engine.on("connection_error", (err: unknown) => {
      logger.error(`Connection error: ${err}`);
    });
    res.socket.server.io = io;

    io.on("connection", onConnection);
  }
  res.end();
};
```

After changing the callback function and nextjs doing its HMR, it is required to call the handler once as described in 2. I do this by reloading my frontend page which sends a request to the socket handler.